# Is calling computed property from inside Vue method multiple times affecting the performance?

Tags: performance, vue.js, structure, computed-properties

I have a problem with structuring my code written in Vue, in relation to computed properties and performance. I'd like to use computed properties - to not violate DRY rule - but I'm worried that it may affect performance.

I need to solve a UI problem and it is largely connected to div height. 
So I take the height value by accesing $refs:

```
var divHeight = this.$refs.divRef.clientHeight;
```

And then I must use divHeight multiple times in my component methods.

Basically I have three options now. Look at this snippet to see what I mean:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/MariuszWoz/pen/YbpQpo).

What is the best way to tackle this issue?

Comment: Also note that I have multiple properties like divHeight and declaring them as computed properties outside function scope reduces code length by about 25%, so that's huge readability improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd like to mention that whatever method you end up using, it's unlikely to yield a significant performance improvement. If performance is your primary concern, then you should profile your webpage to determine which method works best. Most of the time I would preference code readability/maintainability over performance.

**1. No computed properties, declare `divHeight` in every method separately.**

```js
methods: {
  firstMethod() {
    var divHeight = this.$refs.divRef.clientHeight;
    ...
  },

  secondMethod() {
    var divHeight = this.$refs.divRef.clientHeight;
    ...
  }
}
```

This is preferable if the div's height can change, so you do want to fetch the correct height each time the methods are called in case the height was changed.

**2. Make `divHeight` computed property, declare it anyway as a variable inside a method.**

```js
computed: {
  divHeight() {
    return this.$refs.divRef.clientHeight;
  }
},

methods: {
  firstMethod() {
    var divHeight = this.divHeight;
    ...
  },

  secondMethod() {
    var divHeight = this.divHeight;
    ...
  }
}
```

`divHeight` will be calculated once only, the first time the property is accessed. If the div's height changes then `divHeight` will not be recalculated. This solution is not suitable for this situation since computed properties are typically used when that property relies on other observable data properties of that component (`this.$refs.divRef.clientHeight` is not observable by Vue).

**3. Make `divHeight` computed property, use `this.divHeight` multiple times inside a method.**

```js
computed: {
  divHeight() {
    return this.$refs.divRef.clientHeight;
  }
},

methods: {
  firstMethod() {
    this.divHeight/this.divWidth = something;
    this.divHeight... other operations.
  },

  secondMethod() {
    this.divHeight/this.divWidth = something;
    this.divHeight... other operations.
  }
}
```

This is the same as #2 except you're accessing `this.divHeight` multiple times in each method. The only "improvement" this has over #2 is avoiding the property access, which is negligible; but if you're using `this.divHeight` *many* times in a method then perhaps #2 is better to avoid having `this.` everywhere.

---

I would suggest this instead:

```js
methods: {
  divHeight() {
    return this.$refs.divRef.clientHeight;
  },

  firstMethod() {
    var divHeight = this.divHeight();
    ...
  },

  secondMethod() {
    var divHeight = this.divHeight();
    ...
  }
}
```

This is basically the same as #1 except it's a bit shorter because you don't have to type `this.$refs.divRef.clientHeight` everywhere.